# Double For loops in VBA, different subscripts

Tags: excel, vba, loops, double, subscript

I've got a problem with nested loop in VBA. Algorithm that  I need to execute looks like this:

```
Option base 1
arr(4,2)
i = 1 To 4
j = 2 To 100

i = 1, j = 2 If Cells(2, 1).Value = arr(1,1) Then
                Cells(2,11) = arr(1,2)
i = 1, j = 3 If Cells(3,1).Value = arr(1,1) Then
                Cells(3,11) = arr(1,2)
i = 1, j = 4 If Cells(4,1).Value = arr(1,1) Then
                Cells(4,11).Value = arr(1,2) 
.
.
.

i = 1, j = 100 If Cells(100,1).Value = arr(1,1) Then
                  Cells(100,11).Value = arr(1,2)

And if j reaches 100 then

i = 2, j = 2 If Cells(2,1).Value = arr(2,1) Then
                Cells(2,11).Value = arr(2,2)
i = 2, j = 3 If Cells(3,1).Value = arr(2,1) Then
                Cells(3,11).Value = arr(2,2)
i = 2, j = 4 If Cells(4,1).Value = arr(2,1) Then
                Cells(4,11).Value = arr(2,2)
.
.
.

i = 2, j = 100 If Cells(100,1).Value = arr(2,1) Then
                  Cells(100,1).Value = arr(2,2)
```

`And so on, until i = 4`. 
I hope you get the idea :D Now I need to execute this in VBA - right now I have no idea how to do it, all I tried was a failure unfortunately, so I don't even have a code sample for you ;/ I tried things like

```
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 100
      If Cells(j, 1).Value = arr(i, 1) Then
         Cells(j,11).Value = arr(i,2)
      End If
    Next j
Next i
```

But of course it showed "subscript out of range", I also tried something with For Each, but the same problem...

Please help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your attempt above you need a `Worksheet` object to use the `.Cells`. See below:

```
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 100
        If Sheets("mySheet").Cells(j, 1).Value = arr(i, 1) Then
            Sheets("mySheet").Cells(j, 11).Value = arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

If you still run into `subscript out of range` look at your array dimensions as you may need to declare it to take into account `arr(4,1)` and `arr(4,2)`.

More information on the `.Cells` property here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells

Comment: Thanks, even though my mistake was different (wrong upper bound of i...nevermind XD), your answer assured me that my thinking is generally ok. Thanks again!